# What is the address I need to go to on my phone to access locally hosted (laptop) website?

Tags: macos, iphone, osx-yosemite, ios

I started a simple web server using:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 in directory = ~/Dropbox/Distro
```

My host name is "bob"

How do I access the website from my phone on the same network? Using the host name.

I'm trying stuff like http://bob:8000 but that's not working.

Comment: Try the internal IP address instead of "Bob".

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I can get there with the IP address. I just want to use the host name.